# Send recently saved data from controller to DOM in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

On my website, users can reply to statuses.

```
$reply = Status::create([
        'body' => $replyText,
    ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

status->replies()->save($reply);
```

The request is sent through AJAX. If the request succeeds, the reply is generated automatically on the DOM without a page redirect.

And that's cool and all, but I also want users to be able to delete/edit replies they just made! And for that, I would need the ID in my status table of the newly created reply.

Something like...

```
$reply = Status::create([
        'body' => $replyText,
    ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

$status->replies()->save($reply);

$replyID = ID of the status I just saved to database;
return response()->json($replyID);
```

**Update:**

New code based on Eddy's response:

```
        $reply = Status::create([
        'body' => $replyText,
    ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    $status->replies()->save($reply);
    $id = $reply->id;
    return response()->json($id);
```

Does not return anything. If I do $id = "test", however, the JSON response will be "test". So it doesn't look like that's working.

Comment: Do you have `id` as autoincrement for status table? `Model::create()` always returns the created object. also try to return `reply` and see its content. Perhaps your primary has a different name?

Comment: The "id" table is indeed auto incremented. Weirdly enough, when I do return response()->json($reply), it returns EVERYTHING from that row, including the id. I wonder why return response()->json($id) isn't working...

Comment: try to limit like this. `return response()->json($reply->id);`. And please, dont forget to mark my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Literally just tried that before you commented it. return response()->json($reply->id); returns nothing. return response()->json($reply); returns everything, including the "id" field. That's kind of annoying!

Comment: Check your model. Maybe try to add `id` to the `$fillable` array.

Comment: Tried it. Still nothing! Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$reply = Status::create(...); //returns the created object with ID
$id = $reply->id;
```

You can either return the $id or simply return the object itself.

```
return response()->json($reply); //or $id
```

Just `console.log()` the response to see what you return and use it.

Comment: Added an update to my post. $reply->id doesn't seem to return anything.